# Babel and webpack-dev-server not generating compiled file

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, babeljs

This is my webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');

const frontend = {
  entry: [
    './src/js/app.js'
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty'
  },
  module : {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  stats : {
    colors: true
  },
  devtool : 'source-map'
};

module.exports = [
    Object.assign({}, frontend)
];
```

This is my .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["env"]
}
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack --progress --watch",
    "serve": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
```

When I run `npm run serve`, the bundle.js file is not generated in the dist folder but it says it was succesfully compiled.

[image]

However if I run `npm run watch` the file is generated in the dist folder

Comment: How do you run webpack-dev-server in your webpack.config.js file if you did not install it in package.json?

Comment: @pyhazard, it was installed globally

Answer (score 0):

The webpack-dev-server saves the bundle in memory and doesn't save in on disk. It's by design. The bundle is than served on the dev server. This is easy for live reload and etc.

I recommend checking their documentation.
Or simply read their [readme](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/README.md)